# How to disable or replace a specific plugin for this .vimrc file?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I use [spf13](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/) as my vim plugin collection.

[This](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc) is the  .vimrc file.

How can I override only 'general' group bundles?

Or, to be more specific, How can I disable or replace just one plugin?

Thanks!

**updated:** sorry , maybe i didn't make myself clear, what i really want is to disable or replace a plugin in .vimrc.local or .vimrc.bundles.local

i don't want to touch .vimrc file.

**updated2**: Thanks all . i've figured it out .

"let NERDTreeChDirMode=0 and set noautochdir" should works .
But i also need to comment this out (autocmd BufEnter * if bufname("") !~ "^[A-Za-z0-9]*://" | lcd %:p:h | endif) .

Comment: That's right. You never want to touch spf13's version of .vimrc, or you'll have to manually replay your changes on top of his each time you upgrade/reinstall. Better to work through the native hooks like .vimrc.bundles.local, .vimrc.local, .gvimrc.local, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is documented in the [.vimrc](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc) for spf13.

```
" In your .vimrc.bundles.local file"
" list only the plugin groups you will use
if !exists('g:spf13_bundle_groups')
    let g:spf13_bundle_groups=['general', 'programming', 'php', 'ruby', 'python', 'javascript', 'html', 'misc']
endif
```

Remove `general` from the list, or, e.g. `php`, `ruby`, if you're not doing php or ruby development.

For specific plugins, grep for the plugin in the .vimrc, and comment out the line that loads the Bundle, e.g.:

```
" Javascript
if count(g:spf13_bundle_groups, 'javascript')
    " disable JSON plugin:
    " Bundle 'leshill/vim-json'
    Bundle 'groenewege/vim-less'
    Bundle 'taxilian/vim-web-indent'
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

spf13 uses vundle to manage plugins, you can just uncomment/remove the plugin in the `.vimrc`, e.g. to remove command-t remove this line

```
Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
```

If you remove plugins more to the start of the `.vimrc` you might run into issues because a plugin mentioned later relies on them. The easiest way to find out is to experiment.

Ultimately I would suggest you to find plugins yourself you want to use. That's the easiest way to find out what you really need and also why you need to install some other plugin (as a dependency). It will also make it somewhat easier for you to cope with vanilla vim installations.